# io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0 INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Tags: android-studio, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have done everything changed the port and all the things but its showing as
Original error: "Neither ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable was exported"

I am getting exception in eclipse as
"Neither ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable was exported"

whereas I am also not able to see the path in the finder I am adding it from android studio but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the Appium server is not able to locate the Android SDK that you are trying to test.

Make sure that the ANDROID_HOME path is available in system shell profiles (e.g. .bash_profile, or .zshrc). If not available then we need to add them so that the Appium server can connect with the Android SDK

Step 1: Set ANDROID_HOME path

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/your/android/sdk
```

Replace /path/to/your/android/sdk with the actual path to your Android SDK installation directory.

Step 2: Export ANDROID_HOME to be used by Appium by running

```
source /path/to/your/shell/profile
```

Step 3: Verify Environment Variables by running

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

Step 4: Restart the Appium server